# How do I set the NEW trigger values using a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, triggers

How do I set the NEW trigger values using a stored procedure?  For instance, BEFORE INSERT ON myTable, I want to set the NEW value of myTable.someColumn to a given value.  When trying to do so, I get a 1193 error when trying to create the procedure.  Thank you

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `myProc` ()
BEGIN
    //How do I set NEW.someColumn of myTable?
    SET NEW.someColumn=123;
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER myTrig BEFORE INSERT ON myTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    //SET NEW.someColumn=123; //This works, but I want to do the setting within the stored procedure
    CALL myProc();
END$$

DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO myTable(id,data) VALUES (1,"hello");
//Above "should" really do INSERT INTO myTable(id,data,someColumn) VALUES (1,"hello",123);
```

> ## 1193 - Unknown system variable 'someColumn'

EDIT.  The following will work.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `myProc` (INOUT myID int)
BEGIN
    SET myID =123;
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER myTrig BEFORE INSERT ON myTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL myProc(NEW.someColumn);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please let me know why this is such a horrible question.

Comment: I was able to get it working by passing NEW.someColumn from the trigger to the procedure, and using `CREATE PROCEDURE myProc (INOUT myID int)`

Comment: With 3 downvotes and 2 closes, I am obviously asking something wrong.  Please let me know what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not do it exactly the way you started. But you might be able to achieve what you are looking for by having the stored procedure just give you a value, and then use this value within the trigger:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE myProc (OUT param1 INT)
 BEGIN
   SET @value = 123;
 END//

delimiter ;
```

Then you can have your trigger call the stored procedure and use it's value:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrig BEFORE INSERT ON myTable FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    CALL myProc(@columnValue);
    SET NEW.someColumn = @columnValue;
END$$
```

I haven't tested it, just typing straight out of my head. If it doesn't work, please let me know, and I will revise my answer.

Also, let me know, if this is not what you were looking for, or not complete enough, and I will revise my answer.

(p.s. I have no idea why somebody thought this is not a good question.)

Comment: Thanks Marjeta.  Yes, your solution should work.  Also, I edited my original post and showed another solution that will work.  Obviously, my actual procedure is much longer than I showed, and I used a procedure because it is used on multiple tables.  I wonder if everyone thought is was such a bad question because they feel a trigger shouldn't be used with a stored procedure?  Guess we will never know if they don't leave a comment.  Thanks again

Comment: I didn't think your question was bad. Since I gave you a useful answer, I was obviously able to understand it.